# Spring Integration: get all headers involved in an aggration and not just the last one

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-amqp

I have a Spring integration flow defined like this:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "queueName")
                    .id("id")
                    .acknowledgeMode(MANUAL)
                    .autoStartup(autoStartup)
                    .concurrentConsumers(2)
                    .maxConcurrentConsumers(3)
                    .messageConverter(messageConverter()))
                    .aggregate(a -> ...)
                    .handle(serviceActivatorBean, "myMethod", e -> e.advice(requestHandlerRetryAdviceForIntegrationFlow()))
                    .get();
```

And a service activator defined like this:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class ServiceActivator {

    @ServiceActivator    
    public void myMethod(List<> Collection<MyEvent> events) {
        ....
    }    
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to change the `myMethod` to also take a list of particular headers associated with each message in the aggregation. In my case I'd like to get a hold of the `AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL` and `AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG` for each message so that I can perform an ACK or NACK for each message to RabbitMQ (note that I'm deliberately using manual acknowledgement mode in the IntegrationFlow since I want to send the ACK's/NACK's *after* `myMethod` has executed).

I've tried for example this approach:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class ServiceActivator {

    @ServiceActivator    
    public void myMethod(@Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) List<Channel> channels, 
                         @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) List<Long> tags, 
                         Collection<MyEvent> events) {
        ....
    }    
}
```

but here I only seem to get header values for the last message (i.e. `channels` and `tags` are always of size 1 even though there are multiple events in the `events` collection).

I've also tried changing `Collection<MyEvent>` to `Collection<Message>` (`org.springframework.messaging.Message`) in order to try to manually extract the headers but this fails with:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.x.y.MyEvent cannot be cast to org.springframework.messaging.Message
```

since the message has already been transformed by the message converter defined in the IntegrationFlow.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom `outputProcessor` on your `aggregator` to return the message you desire (with lists of channels/delivery tags in headers and list of events in the payload).