# How to dead letter a RabbitMQ messages when an exceptions happens in a service after an aggregator's forceRelease

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle errors that might have occurred in a service that is called after a aggregate's group timeout occurred that mimics the same flow as if the releaseExpression was met.

Here is my setup:

I have a AmqpInboundChannelAdapter that takes in messages and send them to my aggregator.

When the releaseExpression has been met and before the groupTimeout has expired, if an exception gets thrown in my ServiceActivator, the messages get sent to my dead letter queue for all the messages in that MessageGroup. (10 messages in my example below, which is only used for illustrative purposes) This is what I would expect.

If my releaseExpression hasn't been met but the groupTimeout has been met and the group times out, if an exception gets throw in my ServiceActivator, then the messages do not get sent to my dead letter queue and are acked.

After reading another blog post, 
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999096/spring-integration-how-to-handle-exceptions-in-services-after-an-aggregator?rq=1)
it mentions that this happens because the processing happens in another thread by the MessageGroupStoreReaper and not the one that the SimpleMessageListenerContainer was on. Once processing moves away from the SimpleMessageListener's thread, the messages will be auto ack.

I added the configuration mentioned in the link above and see the error messages getting sent to my error handler. My main question, is what is considered the best way to handle this scenario to minimize message getting lost.

Here are the options I was exploring:

- Use a BatchRabbitTemplate in my custom error handler to publish the failed messaged to the same dead letter queue that they would have gone to if the releaseExpression was met. (This is the approach I outlined below but I am worried about messages getting lost, if an error happens during publishing)
- Investigate if there is away I could let the SimpleMessageListener know about the error that occurred and have it send the batch of messages that failed to a dead letter queue? I doubt this is possible since it seems the messages are already acked.
- Don't set the SimpleMessageListenerContainer to AcknowledgeMode.AUTO and manually ack the messages when they get processed via the Service when the releaseExpression being met or the groupTimeOut happening. (This seems kinda of messy, since there can be 1..N message in the MessageGroup but wanted to see what others have done)

Ideally, I want to have a flow that will that will mimic the same flow when the releaseExpression has been met, so that the messages don't get lost.

Does anyone have recommendation on the best way to handle this scenario they have used in the past?

Thanks for any help and/or advice!

Here is my current configuration using Spring Integration DSL

```
@Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer workListenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container =
                new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(rabbitConnectionFactory);
        container.setQueues(worksQueue());
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(4);
        container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        container.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        container.setChannelTransacted(true);
        container.setTxSize(10);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);          
        return container;
    }

  @Bean
    public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter inboundRabbitMessages() {
        AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(workListenerContainer());       
        return adapter;
    }
```

I have defined a error channel and defined my own taskScheduler to use for the MessageStoreRepear

```
   @Bean 
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler(){
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler  ts = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        MessagePublishingErrorHandler mpe = new MessagePublishingErrorHandler();
        mpe.setDefaultErrorChannel(myErrorChannel());
        ts.setErrorHandler(mpe);
        return ts;
    }


    @Bean
    public PollableChannel myErrorChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }
```

```
 public IntegrationFlow aggregationFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(inboundRabbitMessages())               
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(SomeObject.class))             
                 .aggregate(a->{
                    a.sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true);                  
                    a.groupTimeout(3000);   
                    a.expireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
                    a.expireGroupsUponTimeout(true);                    
                    a.correlationExpression("T(Thread).currentThread().id");
                    a.releaseExpression("size() == 10");                            
                    a.transactional(true);
                 }
                )               
                .handle("someService", "processMessages")
                .get();
    }
```

Here is my custom error flow

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorResponse() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("myErrorChannel")
                    .<MessagingException, Message<?>>transform(MessagingException::getFailedMessage,
                            e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(100)))
                    .channel("myErrorChannelHandler")
                    .handle("myErrorHandler","handleFailedMessage")
                    .log()
                    .get();
    }
```

Here is the custom error handler

```
@Component
public class MyErrorHandler {

    @Autowired
    BatchingRabbitTemplate batchingRabbitTemplate;

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myErrorChannelHandler")
    public void handleFailedMessage(Message<?> message) {       
        ArrayList<SomeObject> payload = (ArrayList<SomeObject>)message.getPayload();        
        payload.forEach(m->batchingRabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("some.dlq","#", m));
    }

}
```

Here is the BatchingRabbitTemplate bean

```
    @Bean   
    public BatchingRabbitTemplate batchingRabbitTemplate() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(5);
        scheduler.initialize();
        BatchingStrategy batchingStrategy = new SimpleBatchingStrategy(10, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 30000);
        BatchingRabbitTemplate batchingRabbitTemplate = new BatchingRabbitTemplate(batchingStrategy, scheduler);    
        batchingRabbitTemplate.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
        return batchingRabbitTemplate;
    }
```

**Update 1**) to show custom MessageGroupProcessor:

```
public class CustomAggregtingMessageGroupProcessor extends AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor {
    @Override
    protected final Object aggregatePayloads(MessageGroup group, Map<String, Object> headers) {
        return group;
    }
}
```

Example Service:

```
@Slf4j
public class SomeService  {
    @ServiceActivator
    public void processMessages(MessageGroup messageGroup) throws IOException {
        Collection<Message<?>> messages  = messageGroup.getMessages();
        //Do business logic 
        //ack messages in the group
        for (Message<?> m : messages) {
            com.rabbitmq.client.Channel channel = (com.rabbitmq.client.Channel) 
                    m.getHeaders().get("amqp_channel");
            long deliveryTag = (long) m.getHeaders().get("amqp_deliveryTag");
            log.debug(" deliveryTag = {}",deliveryTag);
            log.debug("Channel = {}",channel);
            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Updated integrationFlow

```
public IntegrationFlow aggregationFlowWithCustomMessageProcessor() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(inboundRabbitMessages()).transform(Transformers.fromJson(SomeObject.class))
                .aggregate(a -> {
                    a.sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true);
                    a.groupTimeout(3000);
                    a.expireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
                    a.expireGroupsUponTimeout(true);
                    a.correlationExpression("T(Thread).currentThread().id");
                    a.releaseExpression("size() == 10");
                    a.transactional(true);
                    a.outputProcessor(new CustomAggregtingMessageGroupProcessor());
                }).handle("someService", "processMessages").get();
    }
```

New ErrorHandler to do nack

```
public class MyErrorHandler {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myErrorChannelHandler")
    public void handleFailedMessage(MessageGroup messageGroup) throws IOException {
        if(messageGroup!=null) {
            log.debug("Nack messages size = {}", messageGroup.getMessages().size());
            Collection<Message<?>> messages  = messageGroup.getMessages();
            for (Message<?> m : messages) {
                com.rabbitmq.client.Channel channel = (com.rabbitmq.client.Channel) 
                        m.getHeaders().get("amqp_channel");
                long deliveryTag = (long) m.getHeaders().get("amqp_deliveryTag");           
                log.debug("deliveryTag = {}",deliveryTag);
                log.debug("channel = {}",channel);
                channel.basicNack(deliveryTag, false, false);
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2** Added custom ReleaseStratgedy and change to aggegator

```
public class CustomMeasureGroupReleaseStratgedy implements ReleaseStrategy {

    private static final int MAX_MESSAGE_COUNT = 10;

    public boolean canRelease(MessageGroup messageGroup) {
        return messageGroup.getMessages().size() >= MAX_MESSAGE_COUNT;
    }
}
```

```
   public IntegrationFlow aggregationFlowWithCustomMessageProcessorAndReleaseStratgedy() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(inboundRabbitMessages()).transform(Transformers.fromJson(SomeObject.class))
                .aggregate(a -> {
                    a.sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true);
                    a.groupTimeout(3000);
                    a.expireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
                    a.expireGroupsUponTimeout(true);
                    a.correlationExpression("T(Thread).currentThread().id");                   
                    a.transactional(true);
                    a.releaseStrategy(new CustomMeasureGroupReleaseStratgedy());            
                    a.outputProcessor(new CustomAggregtingMessageGroupProcessor());
                }).handle("someService", "processMessages").get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some flaws in your understanding.If you use AUTO, only the last message will be dead-lettered when an exception occurs. Messages successfully deposited in the group, before the release, will be ack'd immediately.

The only way to achieve what you want is to use MANUAL acks.

There is no way to "tell the listener container to send messages to the DLQ". The container never sends messages to the DLQ, it rejects a message and the broker sends it to the DLX/DLQ.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @gary In that case, I am assuming I would need to create my own MessageGroupProcessor that would keep track of the Headers need ed to perform the manual acks. In my service activator, after my business logic has completed for that group of messages, I would then do the manual acks. Something similar to what was mentioned here [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507275/spring-integration-get-all-headers-involved-in-an-aggration-and-not-just-the-la)    I updated my post with the new configuration changes.

Comment: You should put a try/catch around the `basicAck`, just in case.

Comment: Thanks again. Another thing I noticed, is that after I have implemented my CustomAggregtingMessageGroupProcessor my releaseExpression is not being respected and its only releasing based on what I set on the SimpleListenerContainer's prefect  count container.setPrefetchCount(5) and not the releaseExpression of the (size==10) . Do I need to write a custom ReleaseStrategy?

Comment: Sorry, looks like that was the issue. I have updated the post to show the custom ReleaseStrategy. Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like I spoke to soon. It looks like the Custom ReleaseStrategy still didnt make it work correctly. Is there something I should be doing? Thanks.

Comment: I am assuming this happening backs have SimpleListenerContainer set to MANUAL acks which based on the [Container Doc] (https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/#containerAttributes) for the prefetchCount "The number of unacknowledged messages that can be outstanding at each consumer. "...so in my case, since the prefetch was set to 5, the group eventually timed out and was only doing batches of 5 vs the 10

Comment: Yes; the prefetch must be large enough to cover all the contents of all outstanding (incomplete) groups. Since you are correlating on the thread, as long as you use the SMLC, that means there will only be one group outstanding on each thread, so you're good as long as the prefetch is large enough to accommodate the group.

Comment: Thanks again @Gary Russell. Based on the fact that I am correlating on the thread, Does it make sense for me to use the  Channel's channel.basicAck(deliveryTag,true) method to acknowledger all the message up the max delivery tag for that message group vs iterating through each message and ack ingt hem one at a time using the Channel's channel.basicAck(deliveryTag,false) method?

Comment: Yes; that is more efficient.